# hoow can I make and receive calls With USA and Canada by using a PBX account, Acrobits softphone, and Google chat?

Tags: ios, applications, iphone, sim

I have an iPhone 4s running iOS 8, I an recently using it in the Middle East, but I would like to make and receive calls to people living in Canada and USA. I have a gmail that has an American mobile number connected to its Google voice. Is their an app that would enable me to make and receive phone calls by using this American phone number to my iPhone. But I don't have the sim for this American phone number, and my iPhone has a sim with a local number from the Middle East installed to it.

Comment: Google Voice does not work Internationally.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about making International calls, and not about Apple products performances.

Comment: @Buscar웃, I think it is on topic: it's about how to make international calls SPECIFICALLY using an iPhone, which requires a VERY different answer if using android or other products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had good luck with [Acrobits Softphone](https://appsto.re/us/FoJUs.i)... it's a SIP soft phone for iOS.  Once you have an appropriate VoIP/PBX account that supports SIP clients, you can use google chat to get your calls into the PBX.

It definitely has some noticeable lag, but it is certainly better than nothing.

You can get a free VoIP/PBX account at pbxes.com (I have no affiliation).

Comment: VoIP is blocked in most Middle Ester countries.

Comment: http://provpnaccounts.com/List_of_countries_which_block_website_content_VOIP_Skype_including_countries_China_UAE_Oman_Syria_Turkey_Malaysia_and_the_continents_of_Asia_Caribbean_Africa_North_America_Europe_and_the_Middle_East-124-articles

Comment: Hey webmarc, i made an account at the pbxes.com websites as you said, now inorder to make international calls on my iPhone I have to use it in the acrobats Softphone app from the App Store right.

Comment: Yep, exactly.  You'll be able to make and receive calls with it.

Comment: Hey webmarc, is the acrobat softphone app from the App Store is the one that costs 6 dollars or is it another one, I am just checking inorder not to buy the application and it would not be it?

Comment: @moeslim91 I just updated the answer with a link to the app.

Comment: Hey webmarc, one more thing, can this app enable my phone to receive call from America and canada on my American number that is linked to google voice, as if the American SIM card is placed inside my phone.

Comment: Yes. The pbxes service and the SIP protocol don't know or care what country you are in.

Comment: hey man how do you use google chat to get your calls into the PBX

Comment: Hey man a little more help would be great, I downloaded the app and signed in with my pbx account, but you said I have to connect my pbx account to google chat in order to make international calls, can you illustrate how to do that.